# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter (Listview , fragment )

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to load a listview in my fragment and the problem with the adapter is the error - `Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter`.

This is the `onCreateView` method in my class :

```
 public class AndroidGUIModifier implements IMyComponentGUIModifier, IFragmentEvents {

    @Override
    public void onCreateView() {
        tv1 = (TextView) fragment.findViewById("xtv1");
        tv2 = (TextView) fragment.findViewById("xtv2");
        lv=(ListView) fragment.findViewById("xdevices") ;

        mydevices = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AndroidGUIModifier.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mydevices);// the problem here : Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtain the `Context` from the fragment and just pass it to the `ArrayAdapter` :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(fragment.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mydevices);
```

Comment: I got this : 
Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(java.security.AccessControlContext, int, java.util.List<java.lang.String>)

Comment: Are you extending `Fragment`?

Comment: public class AndroidGUIModifier implements IMyComponentGUIModifier, IFragmentEvents {

Answer (score 1):

If it is inside a fragment, you need to pass context for the first argument usually like this I think?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mydevices);
```

If you are using AndroidGUIModifier as your fragment, can you try extending the Fragment class?

```
public class AndroidGUIModifier extends Fragment implements IMyComponentGUIModifier, IFragmentEvents {
```

Comment: Are you using the AndroidGUIModifier as your fragment?

Comment: the problem was like said Nika about fragment.getContext() , thank you .